# supervisord frequently crashes when running ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

Tags: ntp, supervisord

I'm running supervisord on one of my servers.  I have a cronjob that updates the clock using ntpdate every few hours, because on EC2 clocks tend to frequently lag.

I've noticed that when the ntpdate command runs, supervisord will frequently crash and have to be restarted.

I've checked the supervisord logs, and I don't see anything.  I have the INFO level turned on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you define *crash*? It dies and is no longer running? If so, that'd be a (serious) bug, and would need to be reported to the [supervisor issue tracker](https://github.com/supervisor/supervisor/issues).

Comment: That's correct.  I have monit running and it restarts it.

Comment: May be because running ntpdate with cronjob would cause a big "jump" in the system time, which may seems abnormal to other programs and cause them to crash. You may configure ntpd properly and let it correct your system time slowly. FYI, http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/basic-ntp-config.html

Comment: I also see problems with this. I have some jenkins build nodes that we used a crontab to run ntpdate every night at 2am. If a build was running when the crontab hit at 2am, the build would end prematurely with the suspect reason "Aborted by Anonymous". This was only on some nodes. Both the nodes are Debian 7.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem among all 3.0, 3.0a, 3.0b versions. 
There's a 100% reproduce path:

1. set system time 1 year before real time.
2. killall one_program_under_supervisoring.
3. you'll see supervisord crashed.

Supervisor heavily depends on system time on calculating program states, if system time changes, the state may be wrong and there will be Assertion. I made a workaround (See in https://github.com/lifsong/supervisor).

It's better that supervisor developers can improve from design perspective. Created an issue: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/281